# How can I save data in form fields if validation don't pass?

Tags: jquery, validation, yii

I have a complex form (CActiveForm) consists of 4 questions with several checkbox lists and radio buttons. When user visits the page, only the first question is visible. The each next question will appear only if at least one checkbox was checked in previous question (jquery).

Now if I submit form, but its validation fails, error messages display above the form, all checkboxes became unchecked and all question except the first one became invisible.

Is there a simple way to save checked checkboxes and display all questions if form's validation fails?

Maybe yii1 have some standard methods for this? Or the only solution is using of Ajax validation?

Comment: You have to post some code in order to get help. Show us your view and your validation settings. Hidden inputs will fire validation so you have to set up rules in order to get it to stop.

Comment: Already solved the issue by adding jquery function for checking form fields to form submit button. If function returns true, form will submit. Don't think that this is a right way, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use something like dependent dropdown [ask show here](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/608/multi-level-dropdown-menu-in-bootstrap) or if you use yii2 [see here](https://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I should using Yii1 in this project and there will be checkboxes lists instead of select fields.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some local storage, either via a SESSION variable in something like PHP or indexDB in Javascript to store the form values each time on submit, before validation.  Then if validation fails, refill in the form with the saved form data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem was because form consists of multiple checkboxes lists and the each next list will appears only if user checked previous. So if I submit form all checkboxes will become unchecked and all checkbox lists except the first one will disappeared.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I think using indexDB could still work though.  If you use an event listener on each form action (checking a box etc) and store the state of each checkbox and which lists are visible to a JSON object, and then store that state inside the indexDB, you could then run on page load a quick function to check if a state is already saved in indexDB and if so, load it to restore the state to each checkbox and each lists visibility.  That is, if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: Yes, this variant will works, but I thought there may be ajax validation rule, that won't  reset the form.